# Functions using structs

Tags: c++, struct

i want to code a function in c++ that calculates and outputs three different values using variables that are associated with their respective structs. the code below shows what im talking about.

```
void calculate() {
struct Master {
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
};

Master theta;
theta.x = 0;
theta.y = 0;
theta.z = 0;

Master phi;
phi.x = 1;
phi.y = 1;
phi.z = 1;

Master psi;
psi.x = 2;
psi.y = 2;
psi.z = 2;
```

for example if the function was:
x+y+z 
the code would return three values 
theta: 0,
phi: 3,
psi: 6,

Comment: What you describe seems easy enough to do, what are you having problems with in particular?

Comment: Can you be more precise on what you want. What function you want to create? (x+y+z ??). Is the struct within the function?

Comment: Why do you have that struct inside the function ? Why not have `calculate` inside the struct `Master` returning the sum `x+y+z` ?

Answer (score 1):

Due to the lack of explanation in the question, I don't see why you have the `struct Master` inside the function `calculate`( which again I feel should not have the return type as `void` ).

I think you were looking for something of this sort :

```
struct Master {
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;

    int calculate() {
        return x + y + z;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Master theta;
    theta.x = 0;
    theta.y = 0;
    theta.z = 0;

    Master phi;
    phi.x = 1;
    phi.y = 1;
    phi.z = 1;

    Master psi;
    psi.x = 2;
    psi.y = 2;
    psi.z = 2;

    int thethaSum = theta.calculate();
    int phiSum = phi.calculate();
    int psiSum = psi.calculate();
}
```